# How to upload an image in MySQL using PHP with where conditon

Tags: php, mysqli

Below is my code and I want upload image in a specific row so I want to use where keyword in SQL query but when I use where keyword in SQL query in below code it doesn't work.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $image = $_FILES['imageup']['tmp_name'];
    $img = file_get_contents($image);
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'aish', 'aish123', 'photo') or die('Unable To    connect');
    $sql = "insert into image (img) values(?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $img);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
    if ($check == 1) {
        $msg = 'Successfullly UPloaded';
    } else {
        $msg = 'Could not upload';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to update and not insert. If the record already exists then you need to do something like `'UPDATE image_table SET image_column = :image_data WHERE id = :id'`